# ASP.NET server controls overview

Tags: asp.net, servercontrols

I am looking for a chart overview of the different server control classes. I have seen it once somewhere but can not locate it anymore. Can someone please provide me with a link?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refwebcontrols.asp

or:

http://www.asp.net/%28S%28dfjoah55n4ywsy45zregske4%29%29/community/control-gallery/

Or are you looking for something more like:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7b645f3a-6d22-4548-a0d8-c2a27e1917f8&displaylang=en

but just for ASP .NET server controls?  I guess it depends a lot on the version of the .NET framework (and Visual Studio, if you're using that).

Comment: I am looking for a hierarchical chart/overview.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ASP.NET Server Controls Hierarchy]

[ASP.NET Server Controls Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310919%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
[Web Server Controls Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310916(v=vs.71).aspx)